# Error de sintaxis en la instrucción INSERT INTO

Tags: base-de-datos, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

Ya me salía el guardado a al perfección en otro programas que desarrolle, pero en este me salió este error y llevo horas sin saber que pasa.

[image: ERROR que me aparece]

Y este es el código que implemente para hacer el guardado de datos

```
 Private Sub btn_signup_root_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_signup_root.Click

    Try

        cadena.Open()

        command = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Normal(username,password) values (@txtRoot,@txtRoot2)", cadena)


        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtRoot.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtRoot2.Text)

        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Save Data", vbInformation, "DB")

        cadena.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
    End Try

    cadena.Close()


End Sub
```

Comment: Prueba de este modo: `command = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Normal(username,password) values(@username,@password)", cadena)` Te falta un espacio antes de `values` y además marcar los parámetros con `@` y llamarlos igual que al usar `AddWithValue`

Comment: @A.Cedano Me sigue saliendo el mismo error y ya probé varios métodos, y esta raro por que ese código lo use en otro y funciono.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner cómo tienes el código ahora pulsando en [edit]?

Comment: Listo ahora lo use de esa manera pero me sale el mismo error @A.Cedano

Comment: Te falta un espacio entre los campos y la palabra `values`. Seguro está quedando algo como `INSERT INTO Normal(username,password)values(...` y ahí falta un espacio.

Comment: Estás cometiendo el mismo error del espacio antes de `values`. Y deja el código como lo tenías con los parámetros. Es más seguro así, de lo contrario es vulnerable a Inyección SQL.

Comment: Si escribes la consulta así: `INSERT INTO Normal(username,password) values (@username, @password)` y pasas bien los parámetros **con los nombres correspondientes**, debería funcionar, y el código queda seguro. Observa que `values`  debe quedar con un espacio en blanco antes y después, sino no se interpretará bien la consulta.

Comment: acabo de actualizar como puse el código pero por alguna razón sigue dándome el mismo error y en otros formularios si me salió @A.Cedano

Comment: en actualizar se sale el mismo erro pero ahora dice <code>Error de sintaxis en la instrucción UPDATE</code>

Comment: Los parámetros **tienen que llamarse igual**. En la consulta lo estás llamando por ejemplo `@txtRoot` y en el `Add` los llamas de otra forma. No sé si me explico. Escribe la consulta así: `INSERT INTO Normal(username,password) values (@username, @password)` pues en el `Add` los parámetros se llaman como `@username` y `@password`. Los nombres de parámetros **tienen que coincidir en ambos lugares**, en la cadena de consulta y en los `Add`.

Answer (score 1):

Si no hay otro problema, el código debería funcionar así sin ningún problema:

```
 Private Sub btn_signup_root_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_signup_root.Click

    Try

        cadena.Open()   
        command = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Normal(username, password) values (@username, @password)", cadena)       
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtRoot.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtRoot2.Text)    
        command.ExecuteNonQuery() 
        MsgBox("Save Data", vbInformation, "DB")
        cadena.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
    End Try

    cadena.Close()

End Sub
```

Inicialmente, la instrucción SQL se estaba interpretando así:

`INSERT INTO Normal(username, password)values(...)` todo junto, porque no estabas poniendo espacios en blanco antes de `values`.

Otro error que estás cometiendo es con respecto a los marcadores. Deben llamarse igual, tanto en la instrucción SQL, como al pasar los parámetros. Esos son marcadores para indicar algo como: *donde puse este marcador, va este dato*.

Comment: !YA ME DEJO¡. Al parecer el parámetro `password` no puedo utilizarlo al cambiarlo por `passwd` dejo de salirme el error y el registro quedo el DB.
Gracias por su ayuda...

Comment: OK, puede que `password` sea una palabra reservada, @AngelRzos